# how to get product id for a particular product in product details page?

Tags: product, admin, product-page, magento-2.2.5

I dont know how to implement this task. I want to display product Id in product view page. Can you please help me?

Comment: On which section you want to display the product id?

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
     echo $product->getId(); // getting product id

Comment: Don't use object manager.

Comment: try this : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-current-category-current-product/

Answer (score 0):

Check for the product object in the file where you want to display product id .

And use below code to get the product id.
If you have product object as $product.
 Then use

```
 $product->getId();
```

That will give you product id.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Block

```
<?php
namespace vendor\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(   
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,

    )
    {       
        $this->registry = $registry;

    }


    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }   

}
?>
```

Get product information In your phtml file

```
<?php
  $currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();
            echo $currentProduct->geId();
            echo $currentProduct->geName();
 ?>
```

If you want to get in current product information in phtml you can use following code.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product information
    echo $currentProduct>getId();
    echo $currentProduct>getName();
?>
```